# Python Error - ws.formula_attributes[f'A1']

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am getting the error below. I am not really sure how else to troubleshoot.

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Prod-Test-Error.py", line 15, in 
ws.formula_attributes[f'A1'] = avg_excel_ref
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'formula_attributes'**

It works fine on my local machine but errors on the server. Other python scripts that use openpyxl on the server works fine. It just ws.formula_attributes.

I have check to make sure both openpyxl and xlsxwriter are installed on the server.

I have isolated the code to the below that is giving the error.

```
import openpyxl
import xlsxwriter


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("path_to_file.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']
avg_excel_ref = {"t": "array", "ref": f"A1:A1"}
ws.formula_attributes[f'A1'] = avg_excel_ref
wb.save("path_to_file.xlsx")
```

Comment: openpyxl-3.1.2 / xlsxwriter -3.1.2

Comment: Yes, there the versions on the server.

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#deprecations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only OpenPyxl version 3.0.10 and below have that method `formula_attributes`. Read this - [Link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html?highlight=formula_attributes#deprecations)